# Sprockets::Environment#path is deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
Sprockets::Environment#path is deprecated
/home/yulong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc6/lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:119:in `rewrite_asset_path'
/home/yulong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc6/lib/action_view/asset_paths.rb:29:in `compute_public_path'
/home/yulong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc6/lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:100:in `compute_public_path'
/home/yulong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc6/lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:67:in `asset_path'
/home/yulong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc6/lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:57:in `block in stylesheet_link_tag'
/home/yulong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc6/lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:47:in `collect'
/home/yulong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc6/lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:47:in `stylesheet_link_tag'
/home/yulong/one/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___567393440_92926490'
/home/yulong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc6/lib/action_view/template.rb:144:in `block in render'
/home/yulong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:55:in `instrument'
/home/yulong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc6/lib/action_view/template.rb:142:in `render'
/home/yulong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc6/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_with_layout'
/home/yulong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc6/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:38:in `render_template'
/home/yulong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc6/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:12:in `block in render'
/home/yulong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc6/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:22:in `wrap_formats'
/home/yulong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc6/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:9:in `render'
/home/yulong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc6/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
/home/yulong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc6/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
/home/yulong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc6/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `_render_template'
/home/yulong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc6/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:250:in `_render_template'
/home/yulong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc6/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:114:in `render_to_body'
/home/yulong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc6/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:30:in `render_to_body'
```

Else, when i install rails, I got an error "file 'lib' not found", but i can't solve it and i think it's relative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest Rails 3.1.rc8, or you can wait for Rails 3.1 final that should be released by tomorrow.

Comment: thx very much~but i got an error:file "lib" not found ,is there any solution?~~~

Answer (score 0):

These deprecations, recently introduced in Sprockets, warnings fixed in rails-3.1.0-rc7. See https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2598 for more detail.

Comment: thanks ,but when i install rc8.i got an error "file 'lib' not found",is there any solution for this??it makes me mad-_-!